# How to clearly display a huge shapefile with many point features?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, visualisation

I have two vector shapefiles, each with 54,000 features. When it's zoomed in on a small region, I can clearly see the feature colors:

[image]

but as I zoom out, this is what I get:

[image]

Any suggestions on how to display the features clearly?

Comment: What is your goal - eg, to have the points draw faster, or to answer a question with the data? Do you simply need to visualize this, or do you need to calculate something?

Comment: Convert it to a raster.

Comment: Scale-dependent symbolization, heatmap,...  there's many possible answers, but no one right one.

Comment: Remove the black outline of the circles. Make a scale dependent style that draws less features when you zoom out. Shapefile with 54000 points is not huge. Small or regular at maximum I'd say.